# boot disk will not load on my Core 2 Duo osx 10.6.8

Tags: macintosh

When I restart holding the option key I do get the Windows DVD (Elementary) boot option, all is normal. When I select it the process starts loading from DVD and hangs with a message   `(`1.
                       2.
                       Select CD-ROM Boot Type : `)`
Keyboard is lock out, the only option is to power off.
I tried the DVD on a Macbook Air running Maverick, worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the DVD is defect.. do you have an usb-stick wich you could format with the Mac? You could use a tool like [UNetbootin](https://unetbootin.github.io/) to create an bootable USB-Stick with the elementary iso file instead of using the DVD.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Rufus for create bootable disk (USB/DVD/CD) Try Rufus this is should be work.